# Assigning latitude and longitude to a particular pixel in satellite image

Tags: georeferencing, image, satellite

Pixel of a satellite images can be assigned latitude and longitude, but how this is done as each pixel represent certain area depending on the resolution of image that can be too high to assign latitude and longitude?

Comment: Are you asking what part of the pixel the geolocation is referring to? There are two common ways: left top and center of the pixel.

Comment: Yes, which part it is? Can we differentiate between center of the pixel and left top.

Comment: That all depends on the dataset and software you are using. GDAL for instance refers to the [top left corner of the top left pixel](http://www.gdal.org/gdal_datamodel.html) when showing the origin. But given the affine transformation you can also calculate the position of the center of the pixel.

Comment: @Kersten It looks like your comments should be posted as an answer

Comment: @Midavalo just did.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That all depends on the dataset and software you are using. GDAL for instance refers to the [top left corner of the top left pixel](http://www.gdal.org/gdal_datamodel.html) when showing the origin. But given the affine transformation you can also calculate the position of the center of the pixel.

Generally there are two common ways that the geolocation refers to: left top and center of the pixel.